# Can a Timer event experience reentrancy?

Tags: timer, vb6, message-queue

I'm examining some dreadful legacy code that has a Timer event with some lengthy code that contains DoEvents calls. A simplified version looks something like this:

```
   Private Sub tmrProcess_Timer()
      'Run some slow processing code here
      DoEvents
      'More slow code here
      DoEvents
      'Lots more slow code and the occasional DoEvents here
      If booComplete Then
         tmrProcess.Enabled = False
      End If
   End Sub
```

The timer has it's Interval set to 250 and the slow code could take up to thirty or so seconds to complete. Note that there is a button on the form that sets booComplete = True when it is clicked.

Given that VB6 is single threaded and that timer messages are low priority is it at all possible for the Timer event to be re-entered during a DoEvents call or will the VB6 runtime block execution of a Timer event if the Timer event is currently executing?

[This reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has some relevant information. In particular it states that WM_PAINT messages are combined into a single message but there is no mention of whether or not WM_TIMER messages are combined.

Comment: I wrote a little test program for this question. (a long running loop within the timer function, with increment a static counter when entering timer event and decrement when leaving, but output the value of the counter after a long running loop.) It seems that VB6 does not reenter the timer routine.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor do you think that is VB6 specific or Windows?

Comment: @Rob: VB6 is windows specific.

Comment: If you have a method that runs longer than the timer interval the interval event is queued and IF anything in your method (a DoEvents), allows events to be fired you could enter the timer event again before your method has exited.

Comment: @jac Are you sure? Remember we're talking about VB6

Comment: This isn't how you use Timer controls for handling long-duration tasks.  You break the task into smaller "quanta" of work, each quantum to be executed for each Timer tick (event).  Don't call DoEvents() at all.  See the VB6 documentation.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor  I mean ... is the non reentrancy specific to VB6 or general to Windows timer events.

Comment: I created a test project with a long running loop and the timer event was re-entered several times, but at seemingly random intervals. Definitely not at the interval I had set. I suggest using rags answer, that is how I have always handled it.

Comment: @Rob: I don´t know, but to be sure I´ll try it later this day in another programming language.

Comment: @Rob: And I´ll try it again in VB6, with a different test program.

Comment: @jac : could you please post your test project as an answer .. see my answer below with a test project which does not reenter the timer event

Comment: @bob77 I'm not asking for best practice or how to refactor, this is _dreadful legacy_ code that someone else has written and I need to understand how it works - or rather how it might fail

Comment: @Hrqls I had deleted my previous example so I tried to recreate it and now it is not re-entering so, ... my bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i expected it would reenter, but it seems not to

have a look at the following test project:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 timer control : Name=Timer1

Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  WindowState = vbMaximized
  Timer1.Interval = 2000
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Static intCount As Integer
  Dim sngTime As Single
  intCount = intCount + 1
  Print CStr(Now) & " Timer event fired " & CStr(intCount)
  sngTime = Timer + 3
  Do While sngTime > Timer
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Print CStr(Now) & " End of timer event " & CStr(intCount)
End Sub
```

- you will see a "start" 2 seconds after the form loads
- you will see an "end" 3 seconds after that
- you will see a "start" 2 seconds after the previous "end" showed
- you will see an "end" 3 seconds after the "start"
- ...

**if the timer would be reentered i would expect 2 seconds between each "start", but there appears to be 3+2=5 seconds between each "start"**

removing the DoEvents doesn't change the behaviour, it just changes the time at which the texts are printed

Comment: Any idea why? Is it the implementation of the VB6 runtime or is it down to the way Windows handles timer messages?

Comment: @ClaraOnager: `WM_TIMER` is reentrant. VB6 timers are not and get explicitly blocked by `MsgBox` function too.

Comment: @wqw That would imply that the implementation of the Windows Procedure in the VB6 runtime prevents re-entrancy

Comment: @ClaraOnager: That, or it's using thread timers and has nothing to do with `WM_TIMER`.

Comment: I concur with this. In my app, if the timer handler takes longer than the timer interval, it is not re-entered. The next invocation of the handler is after the full interval time again after the function exits. So it behaves as if the timer is paused while the handler is being run. DoEvents doesn't affect it, it allows /other/ timers to run, but not the same one.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid reentry, disable the timer till the time taking logic is executed and then enable again.

```
Private Sub tmrProcess_Timer()
  tmrProcess.Enabled = False

  'your time taking logic goes here ......

  tmrProcess.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: While this is a solution to a similar problem it's not an actual answer to this question

Comment: That's true.  rags should edit his answer to prepend the string "Yes. "  Then it would be an actual answer to the question...

Comment: I assume @ClaraOnager wants the timer event to be fired on a regular interval ... if you disable the timer, and enable it again, then the interval is regular+<the time the logic takes> which doesnt have to be regular ... for example she wants the timer to fire every 10 minutes, but the logic takes 30 seconds, then the timer will be fired every 40 seconds instead of every 10 seconds

Comment: Kind of, remember that this is legacy code and I need to understand how it works so I'm not refactoring it, it functions as described in the question - 250ms interval and up to thirty second action

Answer (score 2):

First, most code containing DoEvents doesn't require it, it's a magical word that people feel compelled to incant (but without without knowing why).

> DoEvents allows reentrancy of anything, not just timers.

Your's is a TimerProc. If you had chosen a message then the wm_timer message only comes if the message queue is empty and you ask "are their any messages?". If their is a paint, timer, or mouse move type message pending then if the queue is empty only then are they available.

---

Despite the obviousnous this is the link it came from:

```
> mk:@MSITStore:C:\Program%20Files\Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio\MSDN\2001OCT\1033\kbvb.chm::/Source/vbapps/q118468.htm
```

(of course you have to have same libraries as me installed for this to work.)

Why do you assume the source is the internet?

> Definition of DoEvents in Visual Basic for Applications
>
> Q118468

---

> The information in this article applies to:
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications version 1.0 Microsoft Excel
> for Windows, versions 5.0, 5.0c Microsoft Excel for the Macintosh,
> versions 5.0, 5.0a Microsoft Excel for Windows 95, versions 7.0, 7.0a
> Microsoft Excel 97 for Windows Microsoft Excel 98 Macintosh Edition
>
> ---
>
> SUMMARY The DoEvents function surrenders execution of the macro so
> that the operating system can process other events. The DoEvents
> function passes control from the application to the operating system.
> Some instances in which DoEvents may be useful include the following:
>
> Hardware I/O
>
> Delay Loops
>
> Operating System Calls
>
> DDE Deadlocking
>
> This article also discusses potential problems associated with the
> DoEvents function.
>
> MORE INFORMATION
>
> Hardware I/O If your code waits for an input from any I/O device, the
> DoEvents function speeds up the application by multitasking. As a
> result, the computer does not seems to pause or stop responding (hang)
> while the code is executing.
>
> Example:
>
> Open "com1" For Input As #1 Input #1, x Do Until x = Chr(13) DoEvents
> '... '... Input #1, x Loop Delay Loops In a delay loop, the DoEvents
> function can allow the CPU operating system to continue with any
> pending jobs.
>
> Example:
>
> X = Timer() Do While X + 10 > Timer()
>
> DoEventsLoop Operating System Calls When Visual Basic calls the
> operating system, the operating system may return the control even
> before processing the command completely. Doing so may prevent any
> macro code that depends on an object generated by the call from
> running. In the example below, the Shell function starts the Microsoft
> Word application. If Word is not yet open, any effort to establish a
> DDE link to it will halt the code. By using DoEvents, your procedure
> makes sure that an operation, such as Shell, is completely executed
> before the next macro statement is processed.
>
> Example:
>
> z% = Shell("WinWord Source.Doc",1) DoEvents ... ... DDE Deadlocking
> Consider a situation in which a Visual Basic macro calls an
> application that is waiting for a second application to get some data.
> If the macro does not give control to the second application, the
> result is a deadlock. In DDE conversations between multiple
> applications, using DoEvents removes the possibility of this type of
> deadlocking. Problems Associated with DoEvents Using too many nested
> DoEvents statements may deplete the stack space and therefore generate
> an "Out of Stack Space" error message. This error is referring to the
> application stack space allocated to the Microsoft Excel application.
>
> Make sure the procedure that has given up control with DoEvents is not
> executed again from a different part of your code before the first
> DoEvents call returns; this can cause unpredictable results.
>
> Once DoEvents relinquishes control to the operating system, it is not
> possible to determine when Microsoft Excel will resume the control.
> After the operating system obtains control of the processor, it will
> process all pending events that are currently in the message queue
> (such as mouse clicks and keystrokes). This may be unsuitable for some
> real- time data acquisition applications.
>
> REFERENCES For more information about DoEvents, click the Search
> button in Help and type:
>
> doevents
>
> Additional query words: Sendkeys keystroke Wait XL98 XL97 XL7 XL5
>
> Keywords : Issue type : Technology : kbHWMAC kbOSMAC kbExcelSearch
> kbZNotKeyword6 kbExcel95 kbExcel500 kbExcel98 kbExcel95Search
> kbExcel97Search kbExcel98Search kbExcelMacsearch kbVBASearch
> kbZNotKeyword3 kbExcel500Mac kbExcel500aMac kbExcel500c kbExcel95a
> kbVBA100
>
> Last Reviewed: January 17, 2001 © 2001 Microsoft Corporation. All
> rights reserved. Terms of Use.
>
> ---
>
> Send feedback to MSDN.Look here for MSDN Online resources

Comment: 'DoEvents allows reentrancy of anything, not just timers' - that's a pretty bold statement, are you sure it's correct?

Comment: VB6 Help File. Caution   Any time you temporarily yield the processor within an event procedure, make sure the procedure is not executed again from a different part of your code before the first call returns; this could cause unpredictable results. In addition, do not use DoEvents if other applications could possibly interact with your procedure in unforeseen ways during the time you have yielded control.

Comment: Just one problem, practical experiments show that Timer events don't experience re-entrancy. Do you have a test program that shows re-entrancy?